# Elastic search is not loading the custom analyzer setting using the annotation @Setting(settingPath = "J://setting.json")

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I m trying to create my custom analyzer using elastic search, this is my `setting.json` file located in the given path

```
{   
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "lowercase": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                ]
            }
        }
```

When I start my application then following error occurs

> [  restartedMain] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: analyzer [lowercase] not found

```
@Document(indexName="user",type="userdetails",shards=1)
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Setting(settingPath = “J://setting.json”)
public class user implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    private String userid;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Field(type=FieldType.String,store=true)
    private String username;



    @Column(nullable=false)
    @MultiField(
              mainField = @Field(type = FieldType.String,index = FieldIndex.analyzed,analyzer="lowercase"),
              otherFields = {
                  @InnerField(index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, suffix = "not_analyzed", type =FieldType.String)
              }
            )
    private String city;
```

Comment: Can you share you elastic search entity

Comment: i have shared elastic search entity

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by deleting the previous index, after deletion of index all settings are working properly